# find files with suffix of org or md

Tags: command-line, find

I'd like to find all the files suffix with `.md` or `.org`

```
find ~ -iregex ".*\.md$"
find ~ -iregex ".*\.org$"
```

How could combine them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find ~ -regextype egrep -iregex ".*\.(md|org)"
```

Look into the docs of the `regextype` option to see the supported types of regular expressions. The `egrep`, `posix-extended` and maybe others understand the groups/alternatives in parentheses.

Comment: ... or `".*\.\(md\|org\)"` with the default Emacs `regextype`

Answer (score 5):

Just concatenate your search like says in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1133720/9670273) :

```
find ~ -name "*.md" -o -name "*.org"
```

Explanation :

- `-name` would do the search **recursively** (remove it if you don't want to have subdirectories result)
- `-o` option represents an *OR* operator (it would execute both commands even if there is no `.md` file)
- `~` is the path where you want to start the `find` execution; here, you begins at `~` (so `/home/user` where `user` is your username)

P.S : if you want to use `()`, you need to use the escape character `\` like that :

```
find ~ \( -name "*.md" -o -name "*.org" \)
```

Both of these commands works, but the first is enough in this case.

P.P.S : in case that you want to find files that would got these extensions with uppercases, use the `-iname` option instead of `-name` option, like that :

```
find ~ -iname "*.md" -o -iname "*.org"
```

You would be able to find files named like *README.MD* for example, which aren't shown with the `-name` option